# CKEditor problem with SonataFormatter + SonataNews in Symfony 4.4

Tags: php, symfony, ckeditor, sonata-admin, sonata

I'm trying to integrate SonataNewsBundle in Symfony 4.4.

The CKEditor is *not showing* in the "Content" field for the news post.
I've read through probably all of what's to be found online and couldn't find a way to solve this problem.

`fos_ck_editor.yaml`:

```
editor:
    base_path: "bundles/fosckeditor"
    js_path:   "bundles/fosckeditor/ckeditor.js"
    input_sync: true
    default_config: base_config
    configs:
        base_config:
            toolbar: full

twig:
    form_themes:
        - '@FOSCKEditor/Form/ckeditor_widget.html.twig'
```

`sonata_admin.yaml`:

```
sonata_admin:
    title: 'Something...'
    dashboard:
        blocks:
            - { type: sonata.admin.block.admin_list, position: left }
    options:
        legacy_twig_text_extension: false

    security:
        handler: sonata.admin.security.handler.role

    # DEPRECATED: override templates to enable CKEditor
    templates:
        edit: Admin/CRUD/edit.html.twig

    # extra CSS/JS to for SonataFormatter
    assets:
        extra_javascripts:
            - bundles/fosckeditor/ckeditor.js
            - bundles/sonataformatter/vendor/markitup-markitup/markitup/jquery.markitup.js
            - bundles/sonataformatter/markitup/sets/markdown/set.js
            - bundles/sonataformatter/markitup/sets/html/set.js
            - bundles/sonataformatter/markitup/sets/textile/set.js

        extra_stylesheets:
            - bundles/sonataformatter/markitup/skins/sonata/style.css
            - bundles/sonataformatter/markitup/sets/markdown/style.css
            - bundles/sonataformatter/markitup/sets/html/style.css
            - bundles/sonataformatter/markitup/sets/textile/style.css

# General block configuration
sonata_block:
    blocks:

        # Enable the SonataAdminBundle block
        sonata.admin.block.admin_list:
            contexts: [admin]

        # Enable SonataFormatter block
        sonata.formatter.block.formatter: ~
```

`sonata_formatter.yaml`:

```
sonata_formatter:
    #default_formatter: text
    default_formatter: markdown
    formatters:
        markdown:
            service: sonata.formatter.text.markdown
            extensions:
                - sonata.formatter.twig.control_flow
                - sonata.formatter.twig.gist
                - sonata.media.formatter.twig
        text:
            service: sonata.formatter.text.text
            extensions:
                - sonata.formatter.twig.control_flow
                - sonata.formatter.twig.gist
                - sonata.media.formatter.twig
        rawhtml:
            service: sonata.formatter.text.raw
            extensions:
                - sonata.formatter.twig.control_flow
                - sonata.formatter.twig.gist
                - sonata.media.formatter.twig
        richhtml:
            service: sonata.formatter.text.raw
            extensions:
                - sonata.formatter.twig.control_flow
                - sonata.formatter.twig.gist
                - sonata.media.formatter.twig
        twig:
            service: sonata.formatter.text.twigengine
            extensions: [] # Twig formatter cannot have extensions

    ckeditor:
        templates:
            browser: '@SonataFormatter/Ckeditor/browser.html.twig'
            upload: '@SonataFormatter/Ckeditor/upload.html.twig'
```

Then a small ovverride (for the sake of experimentation) in `sonata_news.yaml`:

```
sonata_news:
(...cut...)
    # override defaults
    admin:
        post:
            class:  App\Admin\PostAdmin
```

Then editing Post just leaves me with a blank "Content" and editable "Raw content" textarea.

When I follow one of the tips I found and apply the `ckeditor` CSS class to the "Content" field with below snippet, the CKEditor indeed shows, but again on the "Raw content" (and not "Content") field, without any reaction/changes to formatter settings, without the actual formats being used...

`PostAdmin.php`

```php
(...cut...)
     protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper)
     {

         // get parent field configuration
         parent::configureFormFields($formMapper);
         $isHorizontal = 'horizontal' === $this->getConfigurationPool()->getOption('form_type');

         $formMapper
            ->with('group_post')
                ->add('content', FormatterType::class, [
                    'event_dispatcher' => $formMapper->getFormBuilder()->getEventDispatcher(),
                    'format_field' => 'contentFormatter',
                    'source_field' => 'rawContent',
                    'source_field_options' => [

                        'horizontal_input_wrapper_class' => $isHorizontal ? 'col-lg-12' : '',
                        'attr' => [

                            //'class' => 'ckeditor',    // NOTE: only way to get it half-assed-working
                            'rows'  => 20
                        ]
                    ],
                    'ckeditor_context' => 'news',
                    'target_field' => 'content',
                    'listener' => true,
                ])
            ->end()
        ;
     }
```

There are no errors on the JS debug console and no 404 assets on the Network console...

** EDIT:

As I did some comparison to the raw HTML output of https://demo.sonata-project.org/ while editing a post, and my own form, I can see I'm missing some inline JavaScript code that references to the format selector and the CKEditor itself. Where does it come from, and why is it not rendering on my end?

** EDIT2:

...and apparently it comes from the `formatter.html.twig`;

```sh
vendor$ grep "This code requires CKEDITOR and jQuery" -r *
sonata-project/formatter-bundle/src/Resources/views/Form/formatter.html.twig:            // This code requires CKEDITOR and jQuery MarkItUp
```

** EDIT3:

I can clearly see the problem is that Symfony 4.4 does not allow the yaml declaration required by formatter bundle, as stated here: https://sonata-project.org/bundles/formatter/2-x/doc/reference/formatter_widget.html

```
twig:
    debug:            '%kernel.debug%'
    strict_variables: '%kernel.debug%'

    form:
        resources:
            # ...
            - 'SonataFormatterBundle:Form:formatter.html.twig'
```

Converting that part into Symfony 4.4 format does not work either:

```
framework:
    templating:
        form:
            resources:
                - 'SonataFormatterBundle:Form:formatter.html.twig'
```

Anyone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Believe it or not, but the only thing missing was:

```
twig:
    form_themes:
        - 'SonataFormatterBundle:Form:formatter.html.twig'
```

in `sonata_formatter.yaml`

Official documentation should be updated for Symfony 4.4!